# ESLint and Prettier indent clashing with multi-line class definition

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I've got a class definition that is too long for a single line. Prettier tries to wrap it but when it does it adds an indentation, which I think is correct. But ESLint doesn't like this so it throws an `indent` error.

There seems to be no config in ESLint to change this behaviour.

[image: Class definition on multiple lines]

Prettier output:

```js
// ESLint throws an error
export default class FormFieldTemplateCheckboxList
    implements ClassComponent<FormFieldTemplateCheckboxListProps> {}
```

ESLint output:

```js
// Prettier formats to the above on save
export default class FormFieldTemplateCheckboxList
implements ClassComponent<FormFieldTemplateCheckboxListProps> {}
```

It's a loop of ESLint and Prettier clashing with what they think is correct.

### Partial Fix

This fix requires the `eslint-config-prettier` plugin, and removing `indent` from the eslint rules.

My old `.eslintrc.json` included the following;

```json
"rules": {
    "indent": ["error", "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 }]
}
```

Now prettier controls the indentation. Now there is no error being thrown, which is what I want to occur.

Comment: Most devs use prettier for formatting and eslint for linting and use this module to achieve it. https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier - might help.

Comment: Yeah that helps, also removing the indent rule from eslint will stop the error. I used the `eslint-plugin-prettier` for eslint and added a rule `"prettier/prettier": "error"` to throw the indent errors again.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution that keeps the indent rules in eslint, but what I've found in my opinion is better.

Remove the `indent` rule from `.eslintrc.json`

```json
"rules": {
    // "indent": ["error", "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 }]
    // ...
}
```

This will now not show any errors with indents. To fix this I installed `eslint-plugin-prettier`.

Put prettier in the plugins list, and then add `prettier/prettier` in the rules and set it to either `error` or `warn`.

This will show an error or warning based on any prettier issues, including indent.

```json
"plugins": [
    "prettier"
    // ...
],
"rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    // ...
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to change the severity based on the prettier rule.